# Setting image variable in fragments

Tags: android

Sorry, I'm still a beginner in coding, but how do I make this code work? actor art is a variable I have from an array.
And it's the name of a image I have in my drawable. This line of code works on any activity type but not on fragments. How do I set image from a variable from an array?

```
int imageId = AppUtil.getImageIdFromDrawable(this, actorart);
ImageView ivCoverArt = view.findViewById(R.id.imgactor);
ivCoverArt.setImageResource(imageId);
```

The error for this is that `this` cannot be used.

This also doesn't work:

```
ImageView imageView= view.findViewById(R.id.imgactor);
imageView.setImageResource(actorart);
```

The error here is that `actorart` is a String but setImageResource is an action for an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, `setImageResource()` takes in an integer, more specifially the ID of the resource.

To get the ID, you can use the following:

`int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + actorart, null, null);`

Comment: int id = getResources().getIdentifier("sg.edu.tp.filmvice:drawable/" + 
      actorart, null, null);
      ImageView imageView= view.findViewById(R.id.imgactor);
      imageView.setImageResource(id);
I tried this, but the images are now blank. no image

Comment: Ok... what is actorart? Can you show where you set it?

Comment: actorart is the name of the image in my drawable, and it's set in my array with a bunch of other shit

Comment: DUDE IT WORKED! It's just an error on my getString from array part. Left 'art' out of 'actorart' THANKS MATE

Comment: No problem! Since it helped, would you mind upvoting and marking the answer as correct for future readers?

Answer (score 0):

`this` cannot be used cause the instance you are refering with this is a Fragment, and I'm pretty sure you need a `Context` parameter.

To fix it get a valid Context:

```
int imageId = AppUtil.getImageIdFromDrawable(getActivity(), actorart);
```

Comment: makes my app crash

Comment: oh now it works because there was an error in my getString. Thanks sincerely mate